# Why doesn't GHC Haskell support overloaded record parameter names?

Tags: haskell, overloading, record, aeson, idris

What I am talking about is that it is not possible to define:

```
data A = A {name :: String}
data B = B {name :: String}
```

I know that the GHC just desugars this to plain functions and the idiomatic way to solve this would be:

```
data A = A {aName :: String}
data B = B {bName :: String}

class Name a where
  name :: a -> String

instance Name A where
  name = aName

instance Name B where
  name = bName
```

After having written this out I don't like it that much ... couldn't this typeclassing be part of the desugaring process?

---

The thought came to me when I was writing some Aeson JSON parsing. Where it would have been too easy to just [derive the `FromJSON` instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.1.0/doc/html/Data-Aeson.html#g:5) for every data type I had to write everything out by hand (currently >1k lines and counting). 
Having names like `name` or simply `value` in a data record is not that uncommon.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Overloading mentions that function overloading introduces some runtime overhead. But I actually don't see why the compiler wouldn't be able to resolve this at compile time and give them different names internally.

[This SO question from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100322/why-doesnt-haskell-ghc-support-record-name-overloading) more or less states *historical* reasons and points to a mail thread from 2006. Has anything changed recently?

Even if there would be some runtime overhead most people wouldn't mind cause most code hardly is performance critical.

Is there some hidden language extension that actually allows this? Again I am not sure ... but I think Idris actually does this?

Comment: Aside: Could someone add a Idris tag to SO and this question? Maybe some one from that community could elaborate too.

Comment: Congrats on being the first question taged idris. If you want to read more about the subject there is a page on the [ghc wiki](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records) and the [conversation on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/kgd4g/the_records_problem_in_haskell_help_build_a/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. GHC docs doesn't seem to have a good ranking in my google results.

Comment: Note that for your specific Aeson problem, you could use [`Data.Aeson.TH`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.1.0/doc/html/Data-Aeson-TH.html) to generate the instances automatically. It lets you normalize the keys e.g. to strip a type prefix from a record field name.

Comment: @shang Thanks for the advice. Sadly the TH parsers don't handle optional fields and my TH-fu isn't good enough to change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the record syntax

```
data A { name :: String }
```

implicitly defines a function

```
name :: A -> String
```

If define both `A` and `B` with a `{ name :: String }`, we have conflicting type definitions for `name`:

```
name :: A -> String
name :: B -> String
```

It's not clear how your proposed implicit type classes would work because if we define two types

```
data A { name :: String }
data B { name :: Text }
```

then we have just shifted the problem to conflicting type class definitions:

```
class Has'name a where
     name :: a -> String

class Has'name a where
     name :: a -> Text
```

In principle this could be resolved one way or another, but this is just one of several tricky conflicting desirable properties for records. When Haskell was defined, it was decided that it was better to have simple if limited support rather than to try to design something more ambitious and complicated. Several improvements to records have been discussed at various times and there are perennial discussions, e.g. [this Haskell Cafe thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2011-November/021170.html). Perhaps something will be worked out for Haskell Prime.

Comment: NO! We already knew that. And rejected it! That kind of brain-dead “thinking” is *exactly* the problem.

What he meant was to have separate name spaces per data type! Just like with OOP, where A.name does not conflict with B.name. (name A) and (name B) shouldn’t either, for the exact same reason.

I mean it could just internally desugar « data A { name :: String } » and « let a = A "Betty" in name a » into « data A { a_Name :: String } » and « let a = A "Betty" in aName a ».

What’s the hold-up?

Comment: @Evi1M4chine: Perhaps you should read some of the copious existing discussions on the issue before proposing something that doesn't actually work very well and then demanding that other people implement it.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine Then what is the type of `name` in your example? It needs to have some sort of principal type, otherwise type inference in general is going to break horribly. Now if you don't care too much about backwards type inference you could desugar into open non-injective type families.

Answer (score 4):

Many, mostly minor reasons.  One is the problem raised by [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14531953/2008899), overloading just on the first argument is insufficient to handle all the useful cases.

You could "desugar"

```
data A { name :: String }
data B { name :: Text   }
```

into

```
class Has'name a b | a -> b where
    name :: a -> b

data A { aName :: String }
instance Has'name A String where
    name :: aName

data B { bName :: Text   }
instance Has'name B Text   where
    name :: bName
```

but that would require GHC extensions (Functional Dependencies) that haven't made it into the standard, yet.  It would preclude using just 'name' for record creation, updates, and pattern matching (view patterns might help there), since 'name' isn't "just" a function in those cases.  You can probably pull off something very similar with template Haskell.

Comment: This doesn't address polymorphic update or do the other typeclasses on the page

Comment: If you need to do polymorphic update, you should probably have "name" still be defined inside a typeclass but make sure it has type Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t (or something "close") so that it can be used as a lens.

At that point though, I'd generally err on the side having different, if long, names of the different lenses, via qualified imports.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found, is to use a preprocessor to solve this definitely rather stupid problem.

Haskell and GHC make this easy, because the whole Haskell parser is available as a normal library. You could just parse all the files, do that renaming scheme (e.g. « data A { name :: String } » and « let a = A "Betty" in name a » into « data A { a_Name :: String } » and « let a = A "Betty" in aName a ») depending on the type of data the name function is applied to, using the type resolver, and write them out for compilation.

But honestly, that should be integrated into GHC. You’re right: It’s silly that this isn’t included.

Comment: But not all types are known at compile time, so you have to worry about things such as principal types. What is the type of `name` in your example? It has to have ONE type for it to work well with the rest of Haskell in terms of type inference and such. If `A` and `B` are both an instance of `Monoid` for example, what does `name mempty` give you?